# Chrome: Increase amount of most visited webpages on the new tab page

Tags: chrome

I am searching for an add-on, or an internal setting, **that increases the amount of most visited web pages** on the new tab page. There is a maximum of eight links, and I would like to increase it.

Notice, not bookmarks, to be added manually. I want Chrome, or the add-on, to automatically update this list, based on the sites I visit most regulary.

Comment: I don't think extesnions can modify the default page. Is a custom page fine?

Comment: I am open to everything that works :-)